# ASP.NET application not working in Network Share

Tags: networking, permissions, network-shares, asp.net

I have a ASP.NET application. While I try to access network share it is throwing an error. I have created a domain user and given permissions to that user.

The following permission are given:

- iis_iusr group
- run as app pool identity
- Windows authentication for database user
- given permission for the domain user for database
- given modify permission on the network share folder for the domain user

But, I still can't access the network share from the application and unable to move file from local location to network share location.

Any solution would be helpful.

Comment: I had the same problem with windows forms applications.. I solved in this way: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/815147 ...

Comment: another attempt is execute the appPool as privileged user (JUST FOR TEST; THAT'S NOT RECCOMENDED)